# create demogdata from demography package in R

Tags: r

I am struggling with using demogdata in R demography package.
my code is as below

```
demogdata("Mx","Exposures",ages = 0:105, years= 1961:2016, "mortality","UK", "Male")
```

Mx and Exposures are my text files(dataset) which contains death rates and exposures from ages 0:105 and for years 1961:2016. the rows and columns in both are the same. i am getting the following error message

**Error in if (nrow(pop) != p | ncol(pop) != n) stop("data and pop are of different size") :    argument is of length zero**

the other code i tried is as below

> demogdata(Mx,Exposures,ages = 0:105, years= 1961:2016, "mortality","UK", "Male")
>   Blockquote

and get the following error
Error in demogdata(Mx, Exposures, ages = 0:105, years = 1961:2016, "mortality",  : 
  Number of ages doesn't match data

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Data? Data? Data?

Comment: @waqas, please provide a dput() of your data. This will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @wl1234 for Mx, V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
1 age 1961.000 1962.000 1963.000 1964.000
2   0    0.025    0.025    0.025    0.023
3   1    0.002    0.001    0.002    0.001
4   2    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001
5   3    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001

Comment: @wl1234 for exposures, V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1 age 1961.0 1962.0 1963.0 1964.0
2   0  402.4  416.9  423.5  430.2
3   1  382.8  401.7  414.5  420.9
4   2  374.5  383.4  401.7  412.7
5   3  366.1  375.9  384.1  401.4

Comment: @waqas, use dput(). We don't want to type everything out to try and help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example